# less verbose way to declare multidimensional std::array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, c++11

Short question:
Is there a shorter way to do this

```
array<array<atomic<int>,n>,m> matrix;
```

I was hoping for something like

```
array< atomic< int>,n,m> matrix;
```

but it doesnt work...

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the error message ? That would help someone to really answer the question. I understand template errors are themselves verbose, but at least a few would help.

Comment: Well it's missing a `>` for starters.

Comment: array<int,5,8> test;
wrong number of template arguments (3, should be 2)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When nested, std::array can become very hard to read and unnecessarily verbose. The opposite ordering of the dimensions can be especially confusing.

For example:

```
std::array < std::array <int, 3 > , 5 > arr1;
```

compared to

```
char c_arr [5][3];
```

Also, note that begin(), end() and size() all return meaningless values when you nest std::array.

For these reasons I've created my own fixed size multidimensional array containers, array_2d and array_3d. They have the advantage that they work with C++98.

They are analogous to std::array but for multidimensional arrays of 2 and 3 dimensions. They are safer and have no worse performance than built-in multidimensional arrays. I didn't include a container for multidimensional arrays with dimensions greater than 3 as they are uncommon. In C++11 a variadic template version could be made which supports an arbitrary number of dimensions (Something like Michael Price's example).

An example of the two-dimensional variant:

```
//Create an array 3 x 5 (Notice the extra pair of braces) 
fsma::array_2d <double, 3, 5> my2darr = {{ 
{ 32.19, 47.29, 31.99, 19.11, 11.19}, 
{ 11.29, 22.49, 33.47, 17.29, 5.01 }, 
{ 41.97, 22.09, 9.76, 22.55, 6.22 } 
}};
```

Full documentation is available here: 
http://fsma.googlecode.com/files/fsma.html

You can download the library here: 
http://fsma.googlecode.com/files/fsma.zip

Comment: u rule, I was wondering why they didnt do this in std::, probably they wanted to keep it pure generic :)

Comment: btw why is .size() meaningless? Doesnt it behave as expected ? arr.size()==dim1, arr[0].size()=dim2

Comment: Perhaps meaningless was too strong a word. What I meant was that it doesn't return the total number of elements in the multidimensional array. btw I agree that something like it should be in the standard. Would make a good alternative to unsafe built-in multdimensional arrays :)

Comment: Could you please explain how your elems array gets populated with the data in the initializer list without any constructor or assignment operators?

Comment: It uses the default constructor so aggregate initialization is possible.

Answer (score 32):

A template alias might help out:

```
#include <array>

template <class T, unsigned I, unsigned J>
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<T, J>, I>;

int main()
{
    Matrix<int, 3, 4> matrix;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no compiler currently implements this feature (at least that I know of, I'd be happy to be proved wrong) :(

Comment: very nice, I was scared that MACRO black magic is the only way(to HELL) :P

Comment: I tested it on clang/OS X before posting.

Comment: btw it is a bit OT, but can somebody guesstimate why it isnt in the standard... i think my  example shows how verbose it can be for 2D matrix of atomic ints.

Comment: @R. Fernandes & Howard GCC has template aliases under no, that means no support in 4.7 or earlier. Ofc they can leave it out from the 4.8, 4.9 ... :(

Comment: Howard's example is somewhat confusing to me because the matrix does *not* map to int[3][4]. Instead, it is like int[4][3]. The definition int[4][3] is an array of 4 elements where each element is an array of 3 integers. That's what is defined above using std::array. Consistent witht that thinking I and J should be swapped in the template alias of Matrix. Better yet, they should renamed Rows and Columns.

Comment: Tip of tree Clang supports template aliases as well.

Comment: Just to be clear, the suggestion to reverse the order of the template parameters **has been applied** in the answer.

Answer (score 30):

A palatable workaround for compilers that don't support template aliases yet is to use a simple metafunction to generate the type:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>

template<class T, std::size_t RowsN, std::size_t ColumnsN>
struct Matrix
{
    typedef std::array<std::array<T, ColumnsN>, RowsN> type; // row major

private:
    Matrix(); // prevent accidental construction of the metafunction itself
};

int main()
{
    Matrix<int, 3, 4>::type matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Solution using variadic templates (slightly more complex than the template alias, but more general purpose)

```
template <typename T, std::size_t thisSize, std::size_t ... otherSizes>
class multi_array : private std::array<multi_array<T, otherSizes...>, thisSize>
{
 using base_array = std::array<multi_array<T, otherSizes...>, thisSize>;

 public:
    using base_array::operator[];
    // TODO: add more using statements to make methods
    // visible.  This is less typing (and less error-prone)
    // than forwarding to the base_array type.
};

template <typename T, std::size_t thisSize>
class multi_array<T, thisSize> : private std::array<T, thisSize>
{
 using base_array = std::array<T, thisSize>;

 public:
    using base_array::operator[];
    // TODO: add more using statements to make methods
    // visible.  This is less typing (and less error-prone)
    // than forwarding to the base_array type.
};
```

There might be some improvement on assigning to non-leaves of the array that could be made.

I tested with a relatively recent build of clang/LLVM.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple, generic version:

```
template <typename T, size_t d1, size_t d2, size_t... ds>
struct GetMultiDimArray
{
    using type = std::array<typename GetMultiDimArray<T, d2, ds...>::type, d1>;
};

template <typename T, size_t d1, size_t d2>
struct GetMultiDimArray<T, d1, d2>
{
    using type = std::array<std::array<T, d2>, d1>;
};

template <typename T, size_t d1, size_t d2, size_t... ds>
using MultiDimArray = typename GetMultiDimArray<T, d1, d2, ds...>::type;

// Usage:
MultiDimArray<int, 3, 2> arr {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
assert(arr[1][1] == 4);
```

Comment: Just be careful: methods like `std::array::size()` will not return the correct value.  Also, methods like `std::array::fill(value_type)` will not work at all.