# typedef a shared pointer that contains a templated class

Tags: c++, class, templates, shared-ptr, forward-declaration

Suppose I have some template class forward declared and I want to typedef a shared pointer to it. How would I do this?

```
template<typename T> class Arg;
typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<Arg> ArgPtr; // Compiler error
```

Comment: Possibly related: [less verbose way to declare multidimensional std::array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7689288/636019)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also probably want template typedef. Read up on Sutter's [article](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/079.htm).

In C++03, you need a hack as:

```
template <typename Arg> struct ArgPtr {
     typedef std::shared_ptr<Arg> ArgPtrType;
};
```

In C++11, you can use template aliasing directly with the `using` keyword:

```
template <typename T>
using ArgPtrType = std::shared_ptr<Arg<T>>;
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `Arg` is not really a type. `Arg<int>` for example would be one. That's why the compiler does not want to compile. You should have written that for example:

```
template<typename T> class Arg;
typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<Arg<int>> ArgPtr;
```

If you used C++11, I guess you could have written that:

```
template<typename T> class Arg;

template<typename T>
using ArgPtr = std::tr1::shared_ptr<Arg<T>>;
```