# Why is the conversion of params for std::thread performed in created thread, not parent one?

Tags: c++11, race-condition, stdthread

I recently learned of this unfortunate behavior of std::thread

```
    void func(std::string param);

    void evil()
    {
    char buff[4096];
    sprintf(buff,"%i",rand());
    std::thread t(func, buff);
    t.detach();
    }
```

(problem here is that buff exipires and conversion from char* to std::string is done in called thread)
Solution is to create thread like this:

```
std::thread t(func, std::string(buff));
```

but my question is what is the reason ISO choose this behavior (that is although perfectly logical when you think about it still a potential source of many bugs...).

Comment: Actually since the `std::thread` constructor copies/moves the data to a thread-local buffer this should work IMHO ...

Comment: @filmor but isnt that still a shallow cpy, aka it copies ptr to array, not the entire array

Comment: I think it is, yes. But that is much more elementary than what you are suggesting (i.e. a shortcoming in `std::thread`'s constructor declaration). Use `std::array`, which has proper copy-semantics and everything should be alright.

Comment: as @filmor is saying there is almost no reason not to use STL data structures instead of old c style arrays

Comment: @aaronman http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689288/less-verbose-way-to-declare-multidimensional-stdarray :)

Comment: That only proves my point, the guy didnt want to use c style so he made his own templated version

Comment: Where did you find this behaviour specified?

Comment: @n.m. Anthony Williams book