# Creating multi-dimensional iterator

Tags: c++, templates, multidimensional-array, casting

I was looking at: [less verbose way to declare multidimensional std::array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689288/less-verbose-way-to-declare-multidimensional-stdarray)

and I saw there was a post on creating multi-dimensional `std::arrays` such that you can do

`array<int, 4, 4, 4> arr;`

and iterate it using:

`arr[0][...][n-1]`

However that code "creates" the `std::arrays` for you. Instead, I'm trying to write similar code that will wrap an already existing array..

Any ideas how I can achieve the same thing? I tried the following but get a large amount of errors :l

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>


template<typename T, std::size_t size>
class multi
{
    protected:
        T ptr;

    public:
        multi(T ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}
        T* begin() {return &ptr[0];}
        T* end() {return &ptr[size];}

        T& operator [](int I) {return ptr[I];}
        const T& operator[](int I) const {return ptr[I];}
};

template <typename T, std::size_t thisSize, std::size_t ... otherSizes>
class multi_iterator : private multi<multi_iterator<T, otherSizes...>, thisSize>
{
    private:
        using base_iter = multi<multi_iterator<T, otherSizes...>, thisSize>;

    public:
        multi_iterator(T ptr) : base_iter(ptr) {}
        using base_iter::begin;
        using base_iter::end;
        using base_iter::operator [];
};

template <typename T, std::size_t thisSize>
class multi_iterator<T, thisSize> : private multi<T, thisSize>
{
    private:
        using base_iter = multi<T, thisSize>;

    public:
        multi_iterator(T ptr) : base_iter(ptr) {}
        using base_iter::begin;
        using base_iter::end;
        using base_iter::operator [];
};

int main()
{
    int arr[4][4] =
    {
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        {5, 6, 7, 8},
        {9, 10, 11, 12},
        {13, 14, 15, 16}
    };

    multi_iterator<int*, 4, 4> iter(&arr[0][0]);
    for (auto it : iter)
    {
        for (auto jt : it)
        {

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The errors are:

```
error: cannot convert 'int**' to 'multi_iterator<int*, 4ull>*' in return
         T* end() {return &ptr[size];}


error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'int**' in return
         T* end() {return &ptr[size];}
```

and so on..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that your template class's iterator accessors are returning the wrong types.  Think of 'multi' as a `vector<int>`.  In your code, begin() returns a `vector<int>*`, when what you meant to return is `int*`. In this case, you want the function signature to be

```
T** begin();
```

Think about an ordinary array of pointers `int*[5] myPointerArray;`.  An 'iterator' in this case is a pointer to an element, which is an `int **`.