# c++ performing operations on functions and declaring functions

Tags: c++, arrays, function, variables, function-declaration

I want to declare a function for the following code which is a matrix that is read from a text file. The code can be seen below.

```
if (infile == "A.txt")
    {
        ifstream myfile("A.txt");
    string line;
    int MatA[3][3];
    int i=0;
    while (getline (myfile, line))
    {
        stringstream ss(line);
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
            ss >> MatA[i][j]; // load the i-th line in the j-th row of mat
        i++;
    }
    // display the loaded matrix                                    
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
            cout<<MatA[i][j]<<" ";
            cout<<endl;
            }

        }
```

Now what I've tried to do is declare this matrix as a function so when I perform operations later on in my code I can just call the function rather than having to re-write the whole matrix. But I'm having difficulty doing this, the attempt I've made to declare the matrix as a function can be seen below.

```
int display (int MatA)
{
     for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
           cout<<MatA[i][j]<<" ";
       cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

However an error occurs saying that `[i]` 'expression must have a pointer to object type'.

If anybody could help that'd be great!

Comment: You are passing an `int`, while for a two-dimentional array you should pass an `int **`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example the function can be defined the following way

```
const size_t N = 3;

void display( const int ( &MatA )[N][N] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) std::cout << MatA[i][j] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The other way is the following

```
const size_t N = 3;

void display( const int ( *MatA )[N], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) std::cout << MatA[i][j] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The functions can be called as

```
#include <iostream>

const size_t N = 3;

// the function definitions

int main()
{
   int a[N][N] = {};
   // some code to fill the matrix

   display( a );
   display( a, N );
}
```

And at last you can use the approach suggested in comments to the post by **@boycy** though as for me then I do not like this approach. 
For example

```
#include <iostream>

const size_t N = 3;

void display( const int **MatA, size_t m, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m * n; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << MatA[i] << " ";
        if ( ( i + 1 ) % n == 0 ) std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
   int a[N][N] = {};
   // some code to fill the matrix

   display( reinterpret_cast<const int **>( a ), N, N );
}
```

Comment: Both of those implementations are not as generic as they could/should [arguably] be; the first forces the matrix to be a square NxN, while the second forces it to be nxN. @SingerOfTheFall's suggestion to pass the matrix as an int** is the most flexible (and usual) method.

The function signature would therefore be `void display( const int** MatA, size_t m, size_t n )` and accessing `MatA[i][j]` for `i` in `[0, m)` and `j` in `[0, n)` will work as desired.

Comment: @boycy In this case you may not pass a two-dimensional array to this function without changing the body of the function. The author did not ask about a generic function definition. If you need a generic approach when either use template functions or containers.

Comment: My apologies, you're right of course. TIL I have forgotten how unpleasant multidimensional arrays are in C++ :-)
It's worth being aware that a function templated on the array dimensions will work fine, but since the template is instantiated once for every unique (m,n) pair it can lead to a bloated binary.

Comment: @boycy: I have to disagree: passing references with compile-time fixed bounds (where possible) is idiomatic in 2014 — multiple levels of pointers and explicit size arguments went the way of the dodo a while ago! I'd use a `template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M> void display(const T (&ar)[N][M]);`, personally, despite the bloat potential. I would have to balance that decision against the number of instantiations I'd actually end up with, though, possibly ending up with an implementation much like the one you suggest, though with a heavy heart. :)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I don't think I advocated `reinterpret_cast`; I had forgotten that array type decay is not recursive. Given a fixed-size array I would generally  opt for the template approach.

@LightnessRacesinOrbit Very true.

A couple of additional thoughts, (since this is after all tagged C++): `std::array` is the C++11 spelling for an array, and does support multidimensional (albeit oddly; see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7689928/322333)), and `std::dynarray` (Array Extensions TS) will provide the runtime-sizing that minimises bloat. Something there for every occasion :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an `int MatA` into display, but you want `int[][]` as an argument. This however does not work that way. So you either have to pass an `int**` and perform pointer arithmetics on it or you will have to create some better accessor for this matrix.

I would suggest taking a look of similar implementations like the [OpenCV Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) type that addresses your issues.